# wordpress widgets not working

Tags: wordpress, drag-and-drop, widget

I am facing an issue in my wordpress site , widget section not working . Not able to drag and drop. I have deactivated the plugins , but still same issue. Please take a look at my site [here](http://adsbeat.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some files from your ftp got deleted. Make sure /wp-content/plugins is still there.